# Python equivalent of setting if not null

Tags: python, null

In ruby I can do this:

```
1.9.3-p448 :001 > a = 1 || 2
 => 1 
1.9.3-p448 :004 > a = nil || 2
 => 2 
1.9.3-p448 :005 > a = 1 || nil
 => 1
```

Is there a similar one-liner in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the [`or`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) operator. From the linked page:

> **x or y**: if x is false, then y, else x

Example:

```
In [1]: 1 or 2
Out[1]: 1

In [2]: None or 2
Out[2]: 2

In [3]: 1 or None
Out[3]: 1
```

Comment: Note that this also "works" for `False or 2 == 2`, `0 or 2 == 2`, and `[] or [2] == [2]`. Make sure you want this behaviour

Comment: @Eric: good point.  The OP used `||`, and `0 || 2` gives 0 in Ruby (compared with `0 | 2`, which gives 2), so we'd need to check on expectations in those cases.

Answer (score 4):

Python's `or` operator is pretty much the equivalent of Ruby's `||` -- and `None` can be used in Python somewhat similarly to how `nil` is in Ruby.

So, for example,

```
a = None or 2
```

would set `a` to `2`.

You can also use a richer "ternary" operator, `something if condition else somethingelse` -- `a or b` is the same as `a if a else b` -- but clearly `or` is more concise and readable when what you want to do is exactly the semantics it supports.

Comment: I think in Ruby the null syntax is `nil`, not `null`. But I agree with the rest of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about modern if-else syntax:

```
x = a if a is not None else 999
```

(or whatever condition you need). This let you test for non-None and is not prone to empty list and similar problems.

General syntax is

```
ValueToBeUsedIfConditionIsTrue if Condition else ValueToBeUsedIfConditionIsFalse
```