# a = b || c in Python

Tags: python

So in JavaScript (and probably other languages), you can assign a default value by using -
`a = b || c` - This is mainly used inside a function but can be used outside of one. If `b` is `undefined` then `a = c`.

I'm looking for a similar method in python. I have a list `s` that contains up to 3 numbers. It will sometimes be 1 or 2. I want to do the python equivalent of the following if possible:

```
a = s[0] || 0
b = s[1] || 9
c = s[2] || 1
```

Because I am not familiar with what this is called, I couldn't do too much searching but I tried and yielded no results.

How can I do this?

Comment: The same way. Use [`or`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#or) operator.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28308648/2301450

Comment: @thefourtheye I didn't know there was a `or` operator but upon trying this, I get a `list index out of range` error.

Comment: What do you want to happen if an element of `s` is 0? Do you want it treated as `False` (not set) or "set to 0"?

Comment: @DavidW I want it to be set to 0.

Comment: @Spedwards In Python, if you try access an invalid index in a list, you will get an error.

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes I know this but in the question I did state it was a list. Plus I just realised your solution won't work if one of the list elements is `0`

Comment: @Spedwards I reopened but if the list element is 0, even the javascript solution you posted will also not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many languages some values evaluate to `False`. In Python this is `False`, `None`, `0`, `0.0`, `[]`, `()`, `{}`, `''` and every object, that has a special method which evaluates to `False`.

In your description you only want to fill a list up to 3 elements. This can be done with:

```
a, b, c = s + [0,9,1][len(s):]
```

Comment: Well isn't that clever. I'm going to mess around with this and see if I can break it but I don't think I will. Thanks!

Comment: No this unbreakable and great. Assuming the list items don't exist and aren't all set to `None` for example

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this works particularly elegantly in Python - you need to consider what happens when the list is too short and you need to distinguish between None (often used to indicate "doesn't exist") and 0 (which also evaluates to False).

You could use

```
a = s[0] if (len(s)>0 and s[0] is not None) else 0
```

It isn't really an elegant idiomatic one-liner though, and you have to remember to write the index of `s` three times.

Alternatively

```
# defined once
def get_default(s,idx,default):
    return s[idx] if (len(s)>idx and s[idx] is not None) else default

a = get_default(s,0,0)
b = get_default(s,1,9)
...
```

might do if you're going to be doing this a lot, and always using lists. I think this may just be a case where what works in Javascript doesn't quite work in Python though, and you have to live with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your first line.But `s` should be `defined`

```
s[0] if (s and s[0]) else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code the alternatives will be chosen if either the list is too short, or if the values in it are false or undefined. This kind of ambiguity is discouraged in Python by design, which one learns to appreciate after a while. For example, you can write:

```
a = s[0] or 0                        # fall back to 0 if s[0] is False
a = s[0] if s[0] is not None else 0  # fall back to 0 if s[0] is None
a = s[0] if s else 0                 # fall back to 0 if s is empty
```

It is up to you to decide which one you mean, and it is fairly rare that you want all of them at once. If you do, write a function expressing the appropriate logic and call it from your expression.